# Can't get R to load for a class despite following the directions

Tags: r

I followed the instruction explicitly and cannot get anything to run. I know almost nothing about programming so any feedback or instructions will be very helpful. Once you have downloaded the file and loaded the swirl library, you will need to run RStudio (or R), and
enter the following in the console:

```
install_course_zip(“YOUR_PATH/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip”,multi=FALSE)
```

Where `YOUR_PATH` is the folder path where you saved the zip file you downloaded in step 1. This
usually looks something like this:

 Mac: `/Users/johndoe/Desktop`

 Windows: `C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop`

I've tried all of the below, for reference my file location is `C:\Users\smari\Desktop` and the attempts I've made are as follows:

```
s\smari\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps5KyXp\downloaded_packages
```

```
> 
> library ("swirl")

| Hi! Type swirl() when you are ready to begin.

> install_course_zip("YOUR_PATH/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(path, exdir = swirl_courses_dir()) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
> Windows: C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop
Error: unexpected input in "Windows: C:\"
> install_course_zip("Windows: C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi+FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""Windows: C:\U"
> install_course_zip(Windows: C:\Desktop\14_740x_Introto_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: unexpected input in "install_course_zip(Windows: C:\"
>  install_course_zip("Windows: C:\Desktop\14_740x_Introto_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""Windows: C:\D"
> install_course_zip("Windows: C:\Users\Shawna\Desktop\14_740x_Introto_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""Windows: C:\U"
> install_course_zip("Desktop\14_740x_Introto_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(path, exdir = swirl_courses_dir()) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
> install_course_zip("C:\Desktop\14_740x_Introto_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\D"
> install_course_zip("Desktop\14_740x_Introto_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(path, exdir = swirl_courses_dir()) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
> install_course_zip("Windows: C:Users\smari\Desktop\14_740x_Introto_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""Windows: C:Users\s"
> install_course_zip("Windows: C:\Users\smari\Desktop\14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""Windows: C:\U"
> install_course_zip("Windows: C:\Desktop\14_740x_Introto_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""Windows: C:\D"
> install_course_zip("C: Users\smari\Desktop\14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip”,multi=FALSE) 
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C: Users\s"
> C:\Users\smari\Desktop
Error: unexpected input in "C:\"
> 
>  install_course_zip("Windows: C:\Users\smari\Desktop_PATH/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""Windows: C:\U"
> 
>  install_course_zip("Windows: C:\\USERS\\SMARI\\Desktop_PATH/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(path, exdir = swirl_courses_dir()) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
> 
>  install_course_zip("WindowsExplorer: C:\\USERS\\SMARI\\Desktop_PATH/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(path, exdir = swirl_courses_dir()) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
>  install_course_zip("WindowsExplorer: C:\\USERS\SMARI\Desktop_PATH/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\S' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""WindowsExplorer: C:\\USERS\S"
>  install_course_zip("WindowsExplorer: C:\\USERS\\smari\\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(path, exdir = swirl_courses_dir()) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
> install_course_zip("WindowsExplorer: C:\USERS\smari\Desktop+_/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""WindowsExplorer: C:\U"
> install_course_zip("C:\USERS\smari\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
> install_course_zip("C:
+ 
+ l
+ jl
+ 
+ install_course_zip("C:\Users\smari\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
install_course_zip("C"
> install_course_zip("C:\Users\smari\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
> install_course_zip("C:\\Users\smari\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\\Users\s"
> install_course_zip("C:\Users\smari\Desktop\14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
> install_course_zip("C:\Users\smari\Desktop\14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
> install_course_zip("C:\\Users\\smari\\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
> install_course_zip("C:\\Users\smari\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\\Users\s"
> install_course_zip("Windows: C:\Users\smari\Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""Windows: C:\U"
> install_course_zip(“C:Users/smari/Desktop/PATH/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip”,multi=FALSE)
Error: unexpected input in "install_course_zip(“"
> install_course_zip("Users/smari/Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(path, exdir = swirl_courses_dir()) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
> ("C: /Users/smari/Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
Error: unexpected ',' in "("C: /Users/smari/Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip","
```

I'm supposed to be able to run a course about using R and then later on input some data to analyze. I need it for homework. Sorry for not having more info- I'm fairly confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Backslash (`\`) is the escape character in `R`. To get around this, you can escape the character itself using `\\`, or using the forwardslash syntax (R does not care if your windows path is declared with forward slashes).

This means that

```
install_course_zip("C:\Users\smari\Desktop_PATH\14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
```

Should be replaced by either:

```
install_course_zip("C:/Users/smari/Desktop/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
```

OR

```
install_course_zip("C:\\Users\\smari\\Desktop\\14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)
```